# It is possible to get a .aar with a Product flavor

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I work on a big project at work, i have been herited 3 months ago. At the moment the project structure is like this :

- Engine : its a library with my entire code (all java classes) with some extern libraries
- App : its a android project but it is just a wrapper for have 2 declinaisons-flavor of the app (different name and icon for commercial purpose). The engine lib is integrated to this app.

Additionnaly, sometimes I do build the engine to .aar for one client who use the library without the app wrapper.

My big problem : the last developepr of this project dont good know gradle and android structure, it is some strange res added twice in Engine and App/ build script / extern lib added twice...

So, before i work on a new major version, i want to refator the build system and simplify it ! In the best world, i want to delete the lib project, add the Engine code to the App, for have just 1 project app and use power of flavors for managing specifics parts.

If i have flavors like this :

- one
- two
- lib

It is possible to use flavor "lib" to get a .aar ?

If you have another solution for simplify or resolve my problem, im over. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having, has you described it, a single application module that outputs both .aar and .apk is not possible afaik, your module has to be a library OR an application, not both. (i.e. in your build.gradle : `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` or `'com.android.library'`).

My guess here will be (Android studio 1.5.1) :

- A single Android Studio project,
- Two modules, one library module and one application module (File -> new... -> New module... -> one "Android Library" and one "Phone or tablet module")
- In the app module, the 2 flavors for your branding.
- Integrate the library module into your app module as a dependency (in your app `build.graddle` dependencies section : `compile project(path : ':yourlibrarymodule')`)

Your ressources can either be stored either in your library (usable in your lib and your app without duplication), in your app in the main flavor (usable in your 2 flavors without duplication) or in your two flavors.

Therefore, you can produce the `.aar` by building your library module, and the two `.apk` by building your app module.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. So, im constrain to keep the solution currently used. Maybe i must clean up and validate the entire process because for the moment its a mess, with ressources duplication and other duplication in flavors folders. In one case, i even have a extern lib (play store) added both with gradle and in local folder :(

Comment: It seemed to me that your current organization is arranged in two projects, right ? If yes you can merge them in one as I say in the answer, therefore you will really simplify a lot of processes (like build variants linking etc.). Anyway yes you should do some cleaning, even restart with a free project, therefore you will master the hole project and be able to document it ^^.

Comment: At the moment I use one project with one module lib "Engine" and one module application, maybe in my inital post i use the wrong terms :)

Comment: Ah alright, my bad for wrongly understanding it ! :/